# How compare set of set in raku-lang？

Tags: set, raku

How to operation two set that contain structured data.

e.g.

```
set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>)) ⊆ set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>), set(<g h i>))#True
set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>)) eq set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>), set(<g h i>))#false
set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>)) ∩ set(set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>), set(<g h i>))#set(<a b c>), set(<d e f>))
```

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean what kind of operations can be used on sets whose elements are also sets? Maybe it boils down to "element identity". Off the top of my head, two literal sets with the same elements are actually different... Please say what you would expect and what's the real result. Also check parentheses, they seem to not be coupled.

Comment: sorry! my bad! It work! just no coupled error ....!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regardless of values in a `Set`, you can use the `eqv` operator to find out if they are the same:

```
$ raku -e 'say <a b c>.Set eqv <c b a>.Set'
True

$ raku -e 'say <a b c>.Set eqv <d b a>.Set'
False

$ raku -e 'say set(<a b c>.Set,<a b d>.Set) eqv set(<d b a>.Set,<c b a>.Set)'
True
```